# A Question About the Order of Learning from the Book "Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism" (1998)

Tags: logic, learning, type-theory, lambda-calculus, intuitionistic-logic

I'm learning from this book: https://disi.unitn.it/~bernardi/RSISE11/Papers/curry-howard.pdf
(Lectures on Curry-Howard Isomorphism - 1998 version) for some project. And due to time constraints, I probably won't be able to cover all of the material in the book, in my study. Luckily, although it would be useful,I don't think I will need to know everything in this book, but rather selected topics. At the moment, I learned the first chapter and something like a third of the second chapter, and from what I learned so far in the second chapter it seems like you don't actually need to know the first chapter in order to learn this chapter, it seems like the two chapters cover separate topics. So, perhaps that's true for other chapters as well. Of course, some of them will require knowledge of previous chapters, especially, I can imagine the 4th chapter on the Curry-Howard isomorphism, but even the chapters that require knowledge of previous chapters, might not require all the previous chapters.

So, it could be very helpful if someone with experience with the topics covered in this book, could list to each chapter all the prerequisites for learning it. Especially, for chapters 4 and 11 (Heyting Arithmetic), that cover material that I totally need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general remark, let me say that if you found that much of the material introduced in these chapters was new to you then you might need some more learning, possibly with other sources for the introductory material.

The first two chapters are different in nature as they cover the very basics for the two distinct topics that are to be linked by means of the Curry-Howard isomorphism: intuitionistic logic and the lambda calculus. Throughout the first part of the book you similarly find other mainly logic chapters (7, 8, 9) and mainly lambda calculus chapters (6, 10). These two groups can be rather independent.

Chapter 3 depends on 1,  and 4 depends on 2 and 3. 5 is independent, and 6 depends on 3. 7 and 9 depend only on 2, 8 and 10 only on 4. Finally, chapter 11 depends on 9 and 4.
This means that you might not need chapters 5 to 8.

Comment: Thank you very much!